# Partial view works different inside areas and outside of them

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-areas, invalidoperationexception

i have two controllers outside the areas and a few areas for my application
my Layout page contains a partial view rendering code:

```
@Html.Action(actionName: "LoginBar", controllerName: "Login")
```

and it is registered in RouteConfig

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "LoginBar",
        url: "loginbar",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Login",
            action = "LoginBar"
        });
```

when i browsing page in HomeController: `/home` it works well

when i'm trying to browse pages inside areas: `/contentedit/articles` the exception throws on a line `@Html.Action`:

```
InvalidOperationException: No route in the route table matches the supplied values.
```

any ideas why this exception throws and what code modifications I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `@Html.Action(actionName: "LoginBar", controllerName: "Login")` you can give `area` as `object` `route` like this way :

```
@Html.Action("LoginBar","Login",new { area = "//your area name//" })
```